# How to set each agent as a different node in Anylogic?

Tags: nodes, anylogic, agents

So I'm working with anylogic and I wanted to create a discrete event model of a factory, I have created an agent called tools and place it according to the coordinates from an excel sheet (there are more than 200 agents) and I have a path which I want to use as the connection between tools.

The problem that I have is that I don't know If it is possible to set a node for each agent that is identified with that specified agent. I need to locate the node in each agent and connect them to the path so later each tool acts as a source and a sink of the product.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a parameter or variable on the Agent and set its type to PointNode.  This variable can represent one of the nodes in your network path, and subsequently be used to direct the agent as such. Is that what you meant?